# How to extract date & ID based on the condition false from the given json, I need to apply the expression in Jmeter extractor. Kindly suggest

Tags: jmeter

How to extract date & ID based on the condition false from the given json, I need to apply the expression in Jmeter extractor. How to capture all the value (id & date) based on the condition false? I don't want the value from this row since it is having value for flag true.

```
     "2021-07-22":[
        {
           "id":"ABC02",
           "Flag":true
        },
        {
           "id":"ABC03",
           "Flag":true
        },
        {
           "id":"ABC04",
           "Flag":true
        },
        {
           "id":"XYZ",
           "Flag":false
        }
     ]
```

JSON:

```
{
   "status":"200",
   "message":"Success",
   "data":{
      "availabilityDates":{
         "2021-07-30":[
            {
               "id":"ABC",
               "Flag":true
            }
         ],
         "2021-07-22":[
            {
               "id":"ABC02",
               "Flag":true
            },
            {
               "id":"ABC03",
               "Flag":true
            },
            {
               "id":"ABC04",
               "Flag":true
            },
            {
               "id":"XYZ",
               "Flag":false
            }
         ],
         "2021-07-03":[
            {
               "id":"ABC05",
               "Flag":true
            },
            {
               "id":"XYZ02",
               "Flag":false
            }
         ],
         "2021-07-25":[
            {
               "id":"XYZ03",
               "Flag":false
            }
         ],
         "2021-07-09":[
            {
               "id":"XYZ04",
               "Flag":false
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code:

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data.availabilityDates.each { date ->
    date.each { entry ->
        entry.value.each { value ->
            if (value.Flag == false) {
                log.info('Date: ' + entry.key + ', id=' + value.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: thank you very much, can i consider the date is stored in Date & ID is stored in id ? Please suggest